# Issues while submitting jars to spark cluster

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to create a basic job in scala using the IntelliJ. Using the following code i have to build the scala and create a jar using `sbt assembly`. Then would submit this jars along with spark-cassandra connector to spark cluster. So, my question is how do i test my scala code without creating the jar in Intellij. 
Also, every time i changes something in my `build.sbt` file. it starts a background task of downloading the dependencies even though i have put provided in the `build.sbt` file. So, how do i make it one time?

[image]

**Code :**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext


object SimpleApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "Cluster_IP")
    val sc = new SparkContext("spark://naresh-pc:7077", "test", conf)
    val csc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
    csc.setKeyspace("KEYSPACE_NAME")
    val rdd = csc.sql("Some_Query")
    rdd.collect().foreach(a => println(a))

  }
}
```

**Build.scala :**

```
name := "SparkCassandraDemo"        
version := "1.0"        
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark".%%("spark-sql") % "1.6.1" % "provided"
```

**Edited question :**

I have implemented what Yuval Itzchakov suggested. But i am getting the following error :
FYI, earlier i used to submit the job in the following manner after creating the jar using `sbt assembly` :

```
bin/spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master spark://naresh-pc:7077 --jars  SOME_PATH/SparkCassandraDemo-assembly-1.0.jar SOME_PATH/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.6.0-M1.jar
```

Which actaully uses the `spark-cassandra-connector-assembly`. So, i guess it is not able to find that jar. So, how do i make it available to the code.

**Error :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange rangepartitioning(cnt#0L ASC,200), None
+- ConvertToSafe
   +- TungstenAggregate(key=[useragent#10], functions=[(count(if ((gid#12 = 1)) cookie#13 else null),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[cnt#0L,useragent#10])
      +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(useragent#10,200), None
         +- TungstenAggregate(key=[useragent#10], functions=[(count(if ((gid#12 = 1)) cookie#13 else null),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[useragent#10,count#16L])
            +- TungstenAggregate(key=[useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12], functions=[], output=[useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12])
               +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12,200), None
                  +- TungstenAggregate(key=[useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12], functions=[], output=[useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12])
                     +- Expand [List(useragent#10, cookie#3, 1)], [useragent#10,cookie#13,gid#12]
                        +- Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@5d1094[useragent#10,cookie#3] 

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.doExecute(Exchange.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ConvertToUnsafe.doExecute(rowFormatConverters.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort.doExecute(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1480)
    at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:17)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, pratik-VirtualBox): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner$.sketch(Partitioner.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.RangePartitioner.<init>(Partitioner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.prepareShuffleDependency(Exchange.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is how do i test my scala code without creating the
>   jar in Intellij

One way of achieving this is creating another module, which doesn't use the `provided` sbt setting but actually compiles the spark jars in order for you to be able to debug your code.

You start by creating an additional module in `build.sbt`:

```
name := "SparkCassandraDemo"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M2",
  "org.apache.spark".%%("spark-sql") % "1.6.1"
)

lazy val sparkDebugger = (project in file("spark-debugger"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "compile")
  )

libraryDependencies ++= sparkDependencies.map(_ % "provided")
```

After that, refresh your `build.sbt` file. You should now see a new module created in the left hand side of IntelliJ called spark-debugger:

[image: New module]

Now, create a debug configuration in Intellij:

1. Go to Edit Configuration:

[image: Edit Configuration]

2. Create a new application configuration:

[image: Application Configuration]

3. Set the newly created spark-debugger module:

[image: Set spark debugger module]

4. Shift + Ctrl + F9, and select the newly created configuration:

[image: Select debugging app]

5. Debug your code:

[image]

Comment: Could you please also tell me the reason of  every time i changes something in my `build.sbt` file. it starts a background task of downloading the dependencies even though i have put provided in the `build.sbt` file. I am using the IntelliJ on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I have edited the question. could you please tell me how to make `spark-cassandra-connector-assembly` jar available.